# How does ggplot2 density differ from the density function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

Why do the following plots look different? Both methods appear to use Gaussian kernels.

How does `ggplot2` compute a density?

```
library(fueleconomy)

d <- density(vehicles$cty, n=2000)
ggplot(NULL, aes(x=d$x, y=d$y)) + geom_line() + scale_x_log10()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(vehicles, aes(x=cty)) + geom_density() + scale_x_log10()
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

A solution to this question already appears on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162425/the-difference-between-geom-density-in-ggplot2-and-density-in-base-r), however the specific parameters ggplot2 is passing to the R stats density function remain unclear.

An alternate solution is to extract the density data straight from the ggplot2 plot, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394321/r-what-algorithm-does-geom-density-use-and-how-to-extract-points-equation-of)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. However, the solution doesnt appear to identify the explicit parameter differences. I'm wondering how I can generate/extract the precise density data from the ggplot density.

Comment: This seems to extract the exact values geom_density plots: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394321/r-what-algorithm-does-geom-density-use-and-how-to-extract-points-equation-of

Comment: I dont think this is to do with the density but how you are applying the log tranform

Comment: Is there an alternate log transformation that I can apply to render them identical?

Comment: eg try `d2 <- density(log10(vehicles$cty),  
              from=min(log10(vehicles$cty)), to=max(log10(vehicles$cty))) ; 
ggplot(data.frame(x=d2$x, y=d2$y), aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line()` : but youll need to tweak the axis labels. Ans`ggplot(vehicles, aes(x=cty)) + stat_density(geom="line") + scale_x_log10()`

Comment: Looks good! Care to turn it into an answer for posterity?

Comment: consider switching to `ggalt::geom_bkde()` for better density estimates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it is not the density calculation that is different but how
the log10 transform is applied.

First check the densities are similar without transform

```
library(ggplot2)
library(fueleconomy)

d <- density(vehicles$cty, from=min(vehicles$cty), to=max(vehicles$cty))
ggplot(data.frame(x=d$x, y=d$y), aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line() 
ggplot(vehicles, aes(x=cty)) + stat_density(geom="line")
```

So the issue seems to be the transform. In the `stat_density` below, it seems as 
if the log10 transform is applied to the x variable before the density calculation. 
So to reproduce the results manually you have to transform the variable prior to the 
calculating the density. Eg

```
d2 <- density(log10(vehicles$cty), from=min(log10(vehicles$cty)), 
                                               to=max(log10(vehicles$cty)))
ggplot(data.frame(x=d2$x, y=d2$y), aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line() 
ggplot(vehicles, aes(x=cty)) + stat_density(geom="line") + scale_x_log10()
```

PS: To see how `ggplot` prepares the data for the density, you can look at the code `as.list(StatDensity)` leads to `StatDensity$compute_group` to `ggplot2:::compute_density`