# Separate stat_density for two density curves in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I am trying to produce a ggplot that shows the histogram of the data as well as two density curves in which one has no adjust value and the other one has.
I tried the following code:

```
ggplot(df, aes_string(x=value))+ 
        geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), colour="grey", fill="grey", alpha=.3)+
        geom_density(colour="red", fill="red", alpha=.3)+
        stat_density(bw="SJ", alpha=0)+
        geom_density(colour="blue", fill="blue", alpha=.3)+
        stat_density(bw="SJ", adjust=5, alpha=0)+
        theme_bw()
```

But this produces this graph with both curves overlapping 100%...

[image]

The .txt dataframe used is [on my google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14YDkpoQr_hw6gt1sbm_oMwbzdwvdHNvL/view?usp=sharing)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please make your [example reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by providing sample data and expected output. I don't understand what you mean by *"one has no adjust value and the other one has"*.

Comment: Within this plot, I want to compare two density curves - one where I want to add an adjust value and one with the standard bandwidth where adjust=1. Both density curves are meant to represent the same data. I now added a link to the .txt file that I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does adding a specific `adjust` argument to `geom_density` not do what you want?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=value))+ 
        geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), colour="grey", fill="grey", alpha=.3)+
        geom_density(colour="red", fill="red", alpha=.3, adjust = 1)+
        geom_density(colour="blue", fill="blue", alpha=.3, adjust = 2)+
        theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, then I come up with another question; ggplot doesn't show expected results. My goal was to determine a density curve for each Stimulus where the density max meet a specific number. This is done using a for loop. When I do `df<-subset(df, Stimulus=="Problema1.rtf"`for example and then do `plot(density(as.numeric(df$value, bw="SJ", adjust=4.3))` a different curve comes out compared to the `ggplot` command using an adjust of 4.3 for the blue curve, for a comparison see: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bVcm4B75YAApFB-1y4N-kYfWXzzhIl7o?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162425/the-difference-between-geom-density-in-ggplot2-and-density-in-base-r I found the information I now wanted - they geom_density and density() apparently use different values which was the reason why I was wondering about the results. When I do it like Chase in this post proposed, I get the results I want. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DominikGrätz You're very welcome; glad it worked out!